# How can we filter row chart dc.js?

Tags: dc.js

I am trying to filter top 10 elements when click top 10 button but not showing up.

Here my code:

```
hastaneRowChart
        .width(300)
        .height(1000)
        .margins({top: 20, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
        .transitionDuration(750)
        .dimension(hastaneDim)
        .group(hastaneGroup)
        .colors(d3.scale.category10())
        .valueAccessor(function (p) {return p.value.vaka;})
        .renderLabel(true)
        .gap(9)
        .title(function(p) { return ""; })
        .ordering(function(d) { return -d.value })
        .elasticX(true)
        .xAxis().ticks(5).tickFormat(d3.format("s"));
```

here filtering code when click:

```
  $("#top10hast").click(function(){
            var h=hastaneDim.top(10);
            hastaneDim.filter(h[0]);
            dc.filterAll();
    });
```

What is wrong with this codes? It doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

by default, dc uses the group.all()

```
chart.data(function(group) {
   return group.all();
});
```

Try to provide your own data function:

```
chart.data(function(group) {
   return group.top(maxItems);
});

$("#top10hast").click(function(){
        var maxItems=10;
        dc.filterAll();
});
```

Beware that providing your own data function might disable some features on some graphs. An alternative is to provide a custom filter to crossfilter

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted

```
var filtered_group = filter_top (group)

hastaneRowChart
  .group(filter_top)    

function filter_top(source_group) {
  return {
    all:function () {
        return source_group.top(maxItems);
        });
    }
 };
```

}

Comment: as of dc.js version 2.0.0-beta.5 this unfortunately does not work on dataTable yet: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/651

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the chart and not the dimension...

```
function filterz() {
    hastaneRowChart.filter(h[0]);
    dc.redrawAll();
};
```

Comment: is is returning an empty result or just 10 results in the wrong order? If the ordering is an issue, try to sorting the data before you select the top 10. Maybe you can provide us with a jsfiddle to make debugging this easier?

Answer (score 0):

1. Filtering on the dimension used by a chart won't affect that chart, only other charts. You'd need another dimension on the same key if you want to affect this chart.
2. `dimension.top()` returns the top rows, not the top values/keys. So you can't pass the result directly to`chart.filter()`; you'll need to extract `hastane` from the row.
3. You are filtering on a single value. Perhaps you mean to filter on the range. Assuming `hastane` is a field of the row:

   hastaneDim.filterRange([h[9].hastane, h[0].hastane]);